# PHP Curl How to extract header's

Tags: php, facebook, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://test.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'x=32423');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
   'OK';
}
```

This is what outputted,when i run this page

> access_token=AAAdsfsdfds32432fadfcazdfadsfadsfdas

How do i extract this and pass it a variable?

Comment: You set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to zero .. how are you even getting the header?  Also, what do you mean extract it?  What does it mean to "pass as a variable?"  Pass to where?

Comment: @tandu:I get the output as access_token from above curl function.pass that access_token to $var so that i can pass to to select query

Comment: use $_POST['token'] to extract, before that make curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANFER, true);

Comment: @SamArulRaj:This is what,is outputted Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to change your CURLOPT_HEADERS to true, and you need

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

and

```
$result=curl_exec($ch)
if( $result=== false)
```

Then, according to an answer I saw elsewhere on SO, this should get you the headers:

```
list($headers,$content) = explode("\r\n\r\n",$result,2);
foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $hdr)
    print_r($hdr); //see what it gives you and then edit this accordingly.
echo $content;
```

Comment: :Can you include your code in my code,i do not get the flow in which code should be written.

Comment: :Where do i put your last part of code,i mean list() ,this part.

Comment: :I got a another problem,below to this code,i've form,now i get the source code of the form ,it is not displaying the form.

Comment: Please ask another question giving the details of your new problem and post a link to it here in the comments and I'll see if I can help you with that as well. (If someone doesn't beat me to it.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your postfields. The postfields should be as follows:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('x'=>'32423'));
```

instead of:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'x=32423'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want

```
$token = end(explode('=', $access_token_string));
```